# grouping by 10 minute intervals of time series data in R and taking the sum

Tags: r

I would like to group by and take the sum of the observations by time intervals of 10 minutes in R.

I have looked into `cut`, and `to.period` from the `xts` package and requires `OHLC` data (Open High Low Close stock data) - I have a different time series data set.

Python code:

```
data_timeidx = data.set_index('timestamp')
data_time_grp = data_timeidx.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10Min'))
```

Data:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-05 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end   <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-05 08:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

time <- seq(start, end, by = 0.05)
d <- data.frame(time)
obs <- nrow(d)
d$data <- rnorm(obs)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a straight forward problem using the `cut` function and the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(group10min=cut(time, "10 min")) %>% summarize(sum=sum(data))



# A tibble: 13 x 2
   group10min              sum
   <fct>                 <dbl>
 1 2015-12-05 06:00:00   63.3 
 2 2015-12-05 06:10:00    9.68
 3 2015-12-05 06:20:00 -139.  
 4 2015-12-05 06:30:00  -18.4 
 5 2015-12-05 06:40:00 -104.  
 6 2015-12-05 06:50:00   28.7 
 7 2015-12-05 07:00:00 -146.
```